# Redbean read all other values from another DB table given one property for that table

Tags: php, mysql, relationship, redbean

Developing a PHP Slim application and I'm using  RedBean ORM to interact with the database (MySQL) I have an employees table and categories table I need to load the values from the categories table according to the category the employee belongs to and show them in the employee details. Like the category name, base pay, tax e.t.c.

So when I select the employee the details of the category in which he belongs to are shown( read from the categories DB)

I have tried loading the values by accessing this output by reading association like this

```
            $category = R::dispense('category');
            $employees = R::related($category, "employee");
```

but the above does not return anything. Any help is welcome